# where can i find information to fix 17.10 installation?

Tags: 17.10, hardware, visual-artifacts

When i open file manager i no longer have partition listings i just have files in home directory displayed horizontally across the screen.

For some reason all of a sudden my visual display be it in a browser or video horizontally flutters like an ocean wave.

Answer (score 1):

In nautilus (the file manager) click on the icon to the right of the looking glass and you switch between the icon view and the listing view. The normal starting point is your home directory.

As to the ocean wave - no idea.